# IIS 7 Taking Too Much Time To Return A JavaScript File Randomly

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have a strange scenario on production server. I have enabled IIS logging and can see that some users are facing slowness and the reason is ext-all.js is not being downloaded at the browser.

There is no special logic to return this file as browser is making simple request for ext-all.js file but it taking time between 2 to 25 mins randomly (not each user facing this scenario).

This is very strange behavior. I have tried by doing following things in IIS

1. disabling static content compression.
2. increasing the quota of the workerprocess for compression with static compression enabled.
3. increasing the bytes from 2700 to 10,000 with static compression
   enabled.

but results could not be improved and still there is entries in the IIS log file for random user at random time.

I also have noticed that there is no load on the server (Processor and Ram are being used till 30% as I have powerful server with powerful specs as compared to usage of my site, there are 300 users connected in peek time)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The only logical explanation for that would be that something else is tying up the thread pool and the request for that script is simply queued up, waiting for an available thread. Unfortunately, it's kind of impossible to say what the issue may be here. I'd first rule out some kind of weird server issue by deploying the app to a new server. Then, if there's still issues look at your app code. Red flags would be anything involving lots of time, like trying to return large files, file processing, etc. Also make sure you aren't creating additional threads (huge no-no for web apps).

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for your valuable input. I would like to bring it in your knowledge that other requests are working fine while this is in wait. I mean new requests are coming and leaving properly but this one is (if stuck) will be stuck.

Comment: That's very strange indeed. Maybe there's something wrong with the file, the drive it resides on, or maybe even just the sector of the drive it resides on. What happens if you copy it to a new location and load it from there?

Comment: thank you again Chris, really appreciate your input. This not happens with every request but a rare ones. If it is a bad sector, will it be hang eventually?

Comment: Chris, When there is no thread available for to entertain this request, user will not see a Server Busy error? Can you explain a little what happens when there is no thread available to entertain this request? and do you know what is the limit of IO threads in iis, there might be any issue with IO threads?

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends on what your timeouts are. In general, if all the threads are busy handling other requests, then the server literally queues up additional requests. As threads return to the pool, it starts servicing the requests in the queue. "IO threads" are not a thing. There is simply the thread servicing the request, which may be traded out on occassion if there's async work being done. However, loading a file asynchronously, for example, doesn't mean a new thread is created for the IO operation.